# VB.net get location of userControl in another container

Tags: vb.net, winforms, windows-forms-designer, subviews

[image]

While referring to the above image: in VB.net,I have four instances of Windows.Forms.UserControl. A,B,C, and D. As you can see, B is in A, C is in B, and D is in C. D has a reference to A, and would like to calculate its location in A. Something like Me.getLocationInContainer(A)  where Me is referring to D. How can I do this? I have done a bit of research and found pointToScreen() and pointToClient() but can't really figure out how to make use of them. The function names are not helping either. I am new to VB.net..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> D has a reference to A ... where Me is referring to D ... I have done a bit of research and found
>   pointToScreen() and pointToClient() but can't really figure out how to
>   make use of them.

That would certainly be the easiest route.  Start by having D convert the point (0, 0) to screen coords.  Then use the reference to A to get it converted back to client coords.  That'll be your answer:

```
Dim ucDscreenCoords = Me.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0))
Dim ucDclientCoordsRelativeToA = A.PointToClient(ucDscreenCoords)
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was after. Simple and straight forward, with an explanation.