# Saving chart in userform as picture

Tags: vb.net, charts, screenshot, userform

A part of this question concerns doing the reverse of the following one:

[VB.net get location of userControl in another container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42079832/vb-net-get-location-of-usercontrol-in-another-container)

No matter what I do, I cannot seem to pinpoint the location of my chart inside a userform (D inside A), therefore what I save is something very different than the chart alone.

So, provided that my userform is too like this:
[image: myUserform]

I need to save a screenshot of D, being D a polar chart with a title and a legend.

My code is:

```
    Dim PicFile As String = FilesFolder & "Pic.png"
    Dim myBounds As Rectangle = A.D.Bounds
    Dim BitMap As New Bitmap(myBounds.Width, myBounds.Height)
    Dim PtChart As Point

    PtChart = A.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0))
    PtChart = A.D.PointToClient(PtChart)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(BitMap)
        g.CopyFromScreen(PtChart, Point.Empty, myBounds.Size)
    End Using
    BitMap.Save(PicFile, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```

Why does this not save the chart (D) correctly?

BONUS: how can I make it work even when I have another application open (say, internet browser) on top of the userform?

Comment: Instead `PtChart = A.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0))    PtChart = A.D.PointToClient(PtChart)` why not just do `PtChart = A.D.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0))`?

Comment: To me it doesn't work. It keeps selecting the correct area from the top left angle of my screen, which is *not* where the userform A appears. I was just trying to understand the logic here.